# How can I call particular array value of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm getting below output as an array.

```
$array = 
        Array
    (
        [12] => Array
            (
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [14] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] => Avaya Implementation  Services
                                        [service_id] => 14
                                        [ser_type_id] => 1
                                        [service_desc] =>Avaya Implementation Servic
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    );
```

I want to print only **service_desc** array value. and I don't want call like $array[12][1][14][0]['service_desc'];

How can I call particular **service_desc** array value of the array?

Comment: you will have to call it as `$array[12][1][14][0]['service_desc'];`, otherwise you will need to re-factor your array, flat it so to speak, or re-factor the way you are generating the array with;

Comment: I would take a close look at whatever code is producing such an ODD array first

Comment: I thought there is any predefined function to catch particular array value. @hassan

Comment: You say you don't want to use the numeric indexes, which implies that the structure is likely to change in the future. Which bits are going to stay constant? It's impossible to answer this question without knowing that.

Comment: You can use `array_walk_recursive` to get value for a key. But still, be clear with your question so that we can help you out

Comment: Yes numeric index values are change but inside values will not change anymore. they are fixed @iainn

Comment: can you give an example @Thamilan

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned that you don't want to call it as `$array[12][1][14][0]['service_desc']` you can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function which will create variables from your array,

```
extract($array[12][1][14][0]);
echo $service_desc;
```

And then you can use your particular key such as `service_desc` as variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function: (Please optimize as per your requirements)

```
$arr ="<YOUR ARRAY>";
$val = "service_desc";
echo removekey($arr, $val);

function removekey($arr, $val) {
    $return = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {

        if (is_array($v) && $k !== $val) {

            removekey($v, $val);
            continue;
        }
        if ($k == $val) {

            echo ($arr[$k]);               
            die;
         }
        $return[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert multidimensional array to single array using `iterator_to_array`

REF:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-to-array.php

```
$service_desc= iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($your_array)), 0);
print_r($service_desc);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Avaya Implementation  Services
    [service_id] => 14
    [ser_type_id] => 1
    [service_desc] =>Avaya Implementation Servic
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_walk_rescursive`](http://php.net/array_walk_rescursive) to frame a single dimensional array of matching keys:

[DEMO](https://eval.in/766834)

```
<?php
$array[12][1][14][0]['service_desc']  = 'Avaya Implementation Servic';
$array[12][1][14][0]['service']       = 'dsfasf';
$array[12][1][114][0]['service_desc'] = 'Avaya Implementation Servicasdfdsf';

$searchKey = 'service_desc';

$desiredValues = [];
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($v, $k) use ($searchKey, &$desiredValues) {
    if ($k === $searchKey) {
        $desiredValues[] = $v;
    }
});

print_r($desiredValues);
```

So this will yield:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Avaya Implementation Servic
    [1] => Avaya Implementation Servicasdfdsf
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use the `array_walk_recursive` function.

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($val, $key) {
    if ($key == 'service_desc') print_r($val); 
} );
```

Instead of the `print_r` statement, you can collect your data into another structure, which you convey using the `use` statement, or with the `$userdata` additional parameter (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php ).

```
$results = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function ($val, $key) use (&$results) {
    if ($key == 'service_desc') {
        $results []= $val;
    }
} );
```

Pay extra care to the `&` in front of the `use (&$results)` otherwise your array of results will be considered immutable inside the callback (i.e. all changes discarded).